# PasteDeploy throwing TypeError when used with uwsgi

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyramid, uwsgi

I'm trying to use the --paste option of uwsgi, to serve a pyramid application, but PasteDeploy is throwing a TypeError (coming from Python3 I guess)

```
File "/home/admin/.mozaiqu.es.env/lib/python3.2/site-packages/paste/deploy/loadwsgi.py", line 277, in loadcontext
    if '#' in uri:
TypeError: Type str doesn't support the buffer API
```

The command i'm using:

```
uwsgi --paste development.ini --socket :3031 -H /home/admin/.mozaiqu.es.env
```

I thought that PasteDeploy and uwsgi were Python3 friendly, they aren't ?

Am I doing something wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just encountered the same problem in python 3.2. I have temporarily resolved the issue by adding the following to the `loadcontext` of `loadwsgi.py`:

```
if isinstance(uri, bytes):
    uri = uri.decode('utf-8')
```

Here is the addition with a little context:

```
def loadcontext(object_type, uri, name=None, relative_to=None,
                global_conf=None):
    if isinstance(uri, bytes):
        uri = uri.decode('utf-8')
    if '#' in uri:
        if name is None:
            uri, name = uri.split('#', 1)
        else:
            # @@: Ignore fragment or error?                                             
            uri = uri.split('#', 1)[0]
```

Comment: This one do the trick, PasteDeploy is not Python3 friendly, at all ... and seems to be no longer maintained.

Comment: @b4stien I use it with Python 3 without issues. What problems do you see?

Comment: This issue is more than 6/7 months old, maybe new version of python3 solved the problem. I ended using python2.7 for this very specific project.

Answer (score 1):

See [Python 3.0 urllib.parse error "Type str doesn't support the buffer API"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/540342/python-3-0-urllib-parse-error-type-str-doesnt-support-the-buffer-api)

It explains the error you are having, just in a different context.
The error is basically a bug in python 3.x. There is a problem in the mesh between byte strings and unicode strings, so several errors arise for this.  The first answer in the post above explains it with more clarity.