# Connect python3 with socket.io

Tags: node.js, sockets, python-3.x, websocket, socket.io

I try to connect socket.io  with python3 but i have some errors
I try this:
python3:

```
conexion =http.client.HTTPConnection('192.168.1.64','3000')
    conexion.request('POST','/socket.io/1/')
    respuesta=conexion.getresponse()
    print(respuesta.read()) #response b'{"code":0,"message":"Transport unknown"}'
    hskey=respuesta.read().split(":")[0]
_ws = websocket.WebSocket(
                    'ws://192.168.1.64:3000/socket.io/1/websocket/'+hskey,
```

the error:

```
 hskey=respuesta.read().split(":")[0]
TypeError: Type str doesn't support the buffer API
```

the server:

```
io.set('origins', '*:*');
io.set("transports", ['websocket', 'flashsocket', 'htmlfile', 'xhr-polling', 'jsonp-polling', 'polling']);
io.set("heartbeat interval", 2); 
//io.set('transports', ['websocket', 'flashsocket', 'htmlfile', 'xhr-polling', 'jsonp-polling', 'polling']);
//io.set('transports', ["websocket", "polling"]);
io.set('authorization', function (handshakeData, accept) {

  if (handshakeData.headers.cookie) {

    handshakeData.cookie = require('express/node_modules/cookie').parse(handshakeData.headers.cookie);

    handshakeData.sessionID = require('express/node_modules/connect/lib/utils').parseSignedCookie(handshakeData.cookie['express.sid'], 'secret');

    if (handshakeData.cookie['express.sid'] == handshakeData.sessionID) {
      return accept('Cookie is invalid.', false);
    }

  } else {
    return accept('No cookie transmitted.', false);
  } 

  accept(null, true);
});
```

the socket.io library for python 3 does not work

i copy the code from here:
[Socket.io connection url?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9729308/socket-io-connection-url)

socket.io version 1.2

Comment: Check the thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/540342/python-3-0-urllib-parse-error-type-str-doesnt-support-the-buffer-api