# django channels str doesnt suppoer buffer API

Tags: django, typeerror, channel, django-channels

I am trying to work with django and channels with the help of https://blog.heroku.com/archives/2016/3/17/in_deep_with_django_channels_the_future_of_real_time_apps_in_django however this code doesn't seem compatible with python 3.4

on my ws_connect:

```
@channel_session
def ws_connect(message):
    prefix, label = message['path'].strip('/').split('/')
    room = Room.objects.get(label=label)
    Group('chat-' + label).add(message.reply_channel)
    message.channel_session['room'] = room.label
```

I get the following error when trying to connect to the socket.

prefix, label = message['path'].strip('/').split('/')
TypeError: Type str doesn't support the buffer API

I only just started working with python 3.4 and have no idea why this breaks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like `message['path']` is a bytes object rather than a string, and trying to apply `strip()` to a bytes object yields that rather cryptic error message. Instead, try `message['path'].decode()` to convert it to a string, then do your stripping and splitting.

See also [Python 3.0 urllib.parse error "Type str doesn't support the buffer API"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/540342/python-3-0-urllib-parse-error-type-str-doesnt-support-the-buffer-api)